# What are some good options for high speed light detection (less response time along with sensitivity)?

Tags: arduino, sensor, light

I wanted to implement a one way wireless optical communication using arduino and LEDs but soon I had to choose sensors. LDRs are very slow and IR does not respond to visible light. My aim is to achieve 3-4 m of transmission so a sensitive sensor will be better for implementation.

Comment: Photodiode  + transimpedance amplifier is the usual solution.

Comment: Are there photo diodes that work in the visible region of spectrum?

Comment: 'slap on forehead' Yes

Comment: Okay my bad. The problem is local vendors in my area don't have them. Thanks for the help. Any suggestions for good sites to buy them.

Comment: What do your local vendors have, exactly? In any case, there's not enough info. No quantification of "high speed." No description of the light environment over which this range is required. But in general you will probably want to (1) narrow-band filter the light wavelengths and (2) narrow-band filter a chosen modulation frequency and (3) narrow the acceptance angle and use baffling to help exclude stray light from odd angles and (4) etc. But who can tell if this is easy or hard. No idea what you can get. No idea what you can apply. No idea how fast. No idea about interference.

Comment: Two commonly used vendors for small orders (at least in the US) are Mouser and Digikey. You should be able to get photodiodes for visible light from either. You'll want to try to order other things at the same time--if you order a single photodiode, you'll probably pay considerably more for shipping than for the diode itself.

Comment: Okay in my case 100 kHz is what I consider high speed. I want it to work in ambient light with the added 50 Hz (in India) noise. No typical frequency specifications until it is in the visible part of spectrum. As far as AWG noise is considered I will suppress it by increasing the power of transmitted signal.

Comment: lol, 100 kHz, what we radio folks usually call "pretty much DC". Not high speed.

Answer (score 3):

Any LED also works as photodiode, for exactly the wavelengths it emits.

In your 50 – 100 kHz case, you can simply use any LED. They should be fast enough. This is totally low-tech! Reverse-bias your LED, add a AC-coupling capacitor, and filter appropriately to extract the signals you're interested in.

India is fairly well-equipped with distributors. Most international distributors also deliver there.

Answer (score 2):

Your design may benefit from Sunlight/lightbulb nulling.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1IRat.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Get that DC/50Hz photon energy out of the signal. Wire an integrator to VDD/2 bias, attach Rin to output of photodiode, pick feedback cap for 10Hz response so your 100KHz data does not get attenuated but DC is fully nulled. Connect OpAmp output to a Darlington in series with the photodiode; if the photodiode produces lots of DC, the Darlington will conduct the DC current to the opposite rail. You'll need a resistor  to VDD/2 to convert the desired 100KHz current into a signal voltage. And place back-back diodes across the resistor.

Comment: A circuit diagram would be much easier to follow.